# cygwin on Windows 7 Professional - error starting XWin Server - "Kerberos credentials have expired"

Tags: windows, cygwin, x11

I have a new laptop with Windows 7 Professional. I download and installed Cygwin including Cygwin-X.

```
uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 DBA-PC 2.4.1(0.293/5/3) 2016-01-24 11:26 x86_64 Cygwin
```

When I try to start an X-Window using
Start->All Programs->Cygwin-X->XWin Server

all I see is s small X-window with this text:

"Network credentials expired
Your Kerberos credentials have expired".

I have tried Google for the error message but I can't seem to find anything helpful.

I am not well-versed with starting X-Window apps on Linux so I don't know where to look. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I will look at that link, thank you. But why would I need to setup kerberos? I wouldn't think I need it for what I am trying to do.

Comment: http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html Here is documentation on using Cygwin-X. Cygwin doesn't necessarily come packaged with all the tools you may need when trying to use it, but you can download packages for it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured it out yet, so I'm just ignoring the message, since I can still run X-Windows apps.